# Android Custom Filetype Content Intent Filter

Tags: android, android-intent, mime-types, intentfilter

I now have two apps with custom filetypes (extensions .ffx and .tcb). When opened from an attachment within Gmail app, the Intent includes neither the filename nor the originally assigned custom mimetypes (application/freqfinder and application/timecardbuddy).

> HOST=(com.google.android.gm.sapi)
>
> SCHEME=content
>
> PATH=/newendian@gmail.com/message_attachment_external/%23thread-f%3A1736258334946004772/%23msg-f%3A1736258334946004772/0.1
>
> FRAGMENT=null
>
> MIME=application/octet-stream

How can I make sure that the proper app is opened? Android doesn't even allow the user to select from multiple apps.

Is there a way to reject an Intent from within the app so that it gets directed properly? Or should I write code to send an explicit Intent from one app to the other?

EDIT: A user contacted me about another app that his device defaults to because it too has a MIME=application/octet-stream file type. Is there really no mechanism for Android to understand that not all application/octet-stream files go to the same app?

Answer (score 0):

> I now have two apps with custom filetypes (extensions .ffx and .tcb)

Custom file extensions have never been practical on Android IMHO. They have been very impractical since Android 7.0, six years ago.

> When opened from an attachment within Gmail app, the Intent includes neither the filename nor the originally assigned custom mimetypes (application/freqfinder and application/timecardbuddy).

I don't know how Gmail would find out about those MIME types. They are not [on the official roster](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml), nor do they follow the rules for vendor-specific MIME types.

> How can I make sure that the proper app is opened?

Your apps would need to have an `<intent-filter>` matching that `Intent` (`content` scheme and `application/octet-stream` MIME type). The app would need to attempt to read in the content and make one of two or three determinations:

1. Yes, this stream has the data in the expected format, in which case the app can go ahead and use it
2. No, this stream does not have the data in the expected format, but it happens to match the other format
3. No, this stream does not have the data in the expected format, and it is unrecognizable

In case 3, you would show some sort of "sorry!" error message. If you elect to also add support for case 2, you could either:

- Show a message in your app explaining that the user needs to use the other app (perhaps with a button to install that app), or
- Forward the `Uri` along to it, including `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` (and, if needed, `FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION`) in your `Intent` to start an activity in the other app (and fall back to the message if you get an `ActivityNotFoundException`, indicating that your other app is not installed)

Comment: Yes it is very clear that Android doesn't handle this well. Are apps not allowed to export custom data? What are the rules for vendor specific MIME types? From your answer, it seems you are saying the only solution is to have my apps explicitly forward the data to the other app

Comment: @NewEndian: "Are apps not allowed to export custom data?" -- sure, but it is unclear what that has to do with Gmail. "What are the rules for vendor specific MIME types?" -- I know that there is an `x-` prefix system, but beyond that, I am fuzzy on the details. "it seems you are saying the only solution is to have my apps explicitly forward the data to the other app" -- for situations where the supplying app (e.g., Gmail) uses a generic MIME type, yes. Custom MIME types are mostly for Web servers, where you can control what MIME types the server uses.

Comment: I would ask why Gmail feels the need to impose anything on the file at all when it's sent. But thank you for the x- suggestion. I'll check it out

Comment: @NewEndian: "I would ask why Gmail feels the need to impose anything on the file at all when it's sent" -- um, well, MIME types originated with email, something like 30 years ago. Email attachments include a MIME type, and the MIME type is chosen by the sender of the email. How those senders do it is up to the sending software and might involve things like the OS. But, for custom MIME types, effectively no email software on the planet will know about them, and the default usually is `application/octet-stream`. As I noted, custom MIME types are mostly for Web servers.

Comment: That still doesn't really explain it. The email software doesn't have to know anything about a lot of what makes up an email. Filename extensions were in use long before email and are still used today, so it doesn't make sense push MIME types in Android but also make them as impractical as extensions